# JestJS: How to test for state value on catch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

My Component `Upload` has the function `example()`, which calls an apollo graphQL mutation (`upload()`).
Before calling the mutation I'm setting `isProcessing` state to `true`. By failing, the state is set back to `false`.

```
example ({ file }) {
  const { upload } = this.props
  this.setState({ isProcessing: true })

  upload({
    variables: { file }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
    this.setState({ isProcessing: false })
  })
}
```

Now I'm trying to write a jestJS unit test for failing mutation call, which should result in a `false` state value:

I'm expecting the `isProcessing` state should be set to `false` by `catch()` call. But the test is failing as it gets still `true`:

```
it('should call mutation and fail', async () => {
  // SETUP
  const wrapper = shallow(<Upload />)
  wrapper.setState({ isProcessing: true })
  console.error = jest.fn()
  // EXECUTE
  await wrapper.instance().example(file)
  // VERIFY
  expect(wrapper.instance().state.isProcessing).toBe(false)
})
```

Comment: Return the promise created by the upload function, this way you can wait for the promise to reject in your test

Comment: @yadejo I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Could you please post an example?

Comment: Sorry, on mobile right now.. I will come back to this question as soon as I can

Comment: @yadejo Would be very thankful if you could post a code snippet...

Comment: `upload` returns a promise, so the promise must be returned from `example` or the test will not wait for it to be fulfilled.  Your `await` is currently receiving `undefined` as the return value from the `example` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`upload` returns a promise, so the promise must be returned from `example` or the test will not wait for it to be fulfilled. Your `await` is currently receiving `undefined` as the return value from the example method.

```
example ({ file }) {
  const { upload } = this.props
  this.setState({ isProcessing: true })

  return upload({   // HERE
    variables: { file }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
    this.setState({ isProcessing: false })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't recognize the missing return.